# WooCommerce Multi-Currency shortcode not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, widgets

I've installed and activated WooCommerce Multi-Currency plugin. I'm still on  the free version but I with that I can add two currencies. This works fine if I try to add the widget to the footer or some other widget area. But I need to have this in the top bar and it seems OceanWP does not have a widget area for that.

So I tried to add it with the shortcode `[woocommerce-currency-selector format="{{code}}: {{name}} ({{symbol}})"]`. But the shortcode just shows up as text. I've tried adding it with `echo do_shortcode` as well but it still shows up as text.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following to your functions.php file

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode');
```

then you can add a 'custom link' item to a menu, such as secondary menu, and add the shortcode to the 'navigation label' field of the custom link.

Answer (score 0):

The https://woocommerce.com/products/multi-currency/ extension now has the ability to have the currency switcher in the menu, in addition to the shortcode you've mentioned.

P.S. There was no free version, if you've got yours from the official WooCommerce marketplace.

P.P.S. I am the author.